# How do I inject dependencies in controller tests?

Tags: java, playframework

This is my class and its constructor and the dependencies.

```
public class FavouriteProfilesController extends BaseController implements CurrentUser, JsonHelper {

    private final UserProvider userProvider;
    private MessagesApi msg;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    public FavouriteProfilesController(
            UserProvider userProvider,
            MessagesApi msgApi) {
        this.userProvider = userProvider;
        this.msg = msgApi;
    } 
    // methods etc...
```

This is the test code I just copied from the docs:

```
public class FavouriteProfilesControllerTest extends WithApplication {

   @Override
   protected Application provideApplication() {
      return new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
              .configure("play.http.router", "javaguide.tests.Routes")
              .build();
   }

   @Test
   public void testIndex() {
      Result result = new FavouriteProfilesController().index(); // Inject dependencies here
      assertEquals(OK, result.status());
      assertEquals("text/html", result.contentType().get());
      assertEquals("utf-8", result.charset().get());
      assertTrue(contentAsString(result).contains("Welcome"));
   }


}
```

The controller has 2 dependencies, UserProvider and MessagesApi, how do I inject/mock them into the controller test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Mockito, you can mock them like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FavouriteProfilesControllerTest extends WithApplication {

   @InjectMocks
   private FavouriteProfilesController controller;

   @Mock
   private UserProvider userProvider;

   @Mock
   private MessagesApi msg;

   @Test
   public void test() {
     Assert.assertNotNull(userProvider);
     Assert.asserNotNull(msg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on what you intend to test. If you mean to mock the whole behavior of UserProvider and MessageApi, using Mockito may be a proper solution. 
In case you want to test controller functionality with real objects, you need to inject real objects. This may be done like this:

```
public class FavouriteProfilesControllerTest extends WithApplication {
    @Test
    public void testIndex() {
        running(Helpers.fakeApplication(), () -> {
            RequestBuilder mockActionRequest = Helpers.fakeRequest(
                controllers.routes.FavouriteProfilesController.index());
            Result result = Helpers.route(mockActionRequest);
            assertEquals(OK, result.status());
            assertEquals("text/html", result.contentType().get());
            assertEquals("utf-8", result.charset().get());
            assertTrue(contentAsString(result).contains("Welcome"));
        });
    }
}
```

Using of GuiceApplicationBuilder is not necessary, if you do not mean to use different injection binding for your test. Call to Helpers.fakeApplication() invokes the default dependency injection.

You can find more about unit testing in Play [here](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/06/unit-testing-powermock-mocking-play.html).

Comment: Thanks I'll try that at home.